# Laravel Excel handle error when file is open

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel

I'm using Laravel Excel 2.1.0 in a local project to write a row into an excel file.

This is my code:

```
$filePath = storage_path('myfile.xls');
$rows = \Excel::load($filePath, function($reader) {
    $sheet = $reader->sheet(0);
    $sheet->appendRow(
        array(
             'Hello'
        )
    );
});
```

Everything works and a new line was appended to my file.

Sometimes can happens the excel file is opened while user try to append a new line. In this case Laravel, rightly, show me this error:

```
fopen(mypath\myfile.xls): failed to open stream: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

How can I handle this error in order to skip the function and go on with my code without append the row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved in this way:

```
$filePath = storage_path('myfile.xls');
$fp = @fopen($filePath, "r+");
if($fp) {
    $rows = \Excel::load($filePath, function($reader) {
        $sheet = $reader->sheet(0);
        $sheet->appendRow(
            array(
                 'Hello'
            )
        );
    });
}
```